# Pycharm does not use my GPU when running Yolo2 algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pycharm, yolo

I have tried unsuccessfully to make my video card used in training and image processing for object recognition. I have used Pycharm as an IDE and made all the necessary settings for my system environment.
I'm running on **Windows 10**. I installed Cuda Tookit 9.0 and cuDNN for the version. I also installed tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 using conda.
In my project I have both tensorflow 1.13.1 and tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 installed. I've tried to run the algorithm without tensorflow, using only tensorflow-gpu, but the execution gives an error.
My video card and a GT 625M.
I am showing images of my environment configuration and the main codes that I am using. I would love a solution that solves my problem, as I have spent more than 5 days running a training with just under 200 images, something that with the use of GPU I am sure that it would not take more than a few hours.

1- Treining Code

```
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
#opções do treino
options = {"model": "cfg/yolo-new.cfg", 
           "load": "bin/yolo.weights",
           "batch": 1,
           "epoch": 100,
           "gpu": 1.0,
           "train": True,
           "annotation": "DataSet-Part/_DataSetNovo_Annotation/",
           "dataset": "DataSet-Part/_DataSetNovo_Image/"}
#configurando a rede com as opções
tfnet = TFNet(options)
#treino
tfnet.train()
```

2 - image recognition code

```
#importar biblioteca numpy
import numpy as np
#importa biblioteca da rede
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
#importar opencv
import cv2

#função para criar o retangulo 
def boxing(original_img , predictions):
    newImage = np.copy(original_img)
    #cria um box pra cada objeto detectado
    for result in predictions:
        top_x = result['topleft']['x']
        top_y = result['topleft']['y']

        btm_x = result['bottomright']['x']
        btm_y = result['bottomright']['y']

        confidence = result['confidence']
        label = result['label'] + " " + str(round(confidence, 3))
        #se for maior que 30% mostra
        if confidence > 0.3:
            #desenha o retangulo
            newImage = cv2.rectangle(newImage, (top_x, top_y), (btm_x, btm_y), (255,0,0), 6)
            #escreve o texto
            newImage = cv2.putText(newImage, label, (top_x, top_y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX , 1, (28, 28, 28), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/davin/source/repos/Yolo 3/darkflow-master/Novas Imagens/"+"novaImage.jpg", newImage)
    return newImage

#opções para carregar o modelo
options = {"model": "cfg/yolo-new.cfg",
           "load": -1,
           "gpu": 1.0}
#configura a rede com as opções
tfnet2 = TFNet(options)
#carrega a rede
tfnet2.load_from_ckpt()
#Le a imagem
original_img = cv2.imread("sample_img/8.jpg")
#Reconhece objetos na imagem
results = tfnet2.return_predict(original_img)
if results:
        print("\nResults---------------------------------------------------")
        #Para cada objeto reconhecido printa o nome e com qual confiança
        for y in range(0, len(results)):
            print("Label:%s\tConfidence:%f"%(results[y]['label'], results[y]['confidence']))

#mostra imagem
cv2.imshow('image',boxing(original_img, results))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

3 - code for recognition with webcam

```
#importar biblioteca numpy
import numpy as np
#importa biblioteca da rede
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
#importar opencv
import cv2

#função para criar o retangulo 
def boxing(original_img , predictions):
    newImage = np.copy(original_img)
    #cria um box pra cada objeto detectado
    for result in predictions:
        top_x = result['topleft']['x']
        top_y = result['topleft']['y']

        btm_x = result['bottomright']['x']
        btm_y = result['bottomright']['y']

        confidence = result['confidence']
        label = result['label'] + " " + str(round(confidence, 3))
        #se for maior que 30% mostra
        if confidence > 0.3:
            #desenha o retangulo
            newImage = cv2.rectangle(newImage, (top_x, top_y), (btm_x, btm_y), (255,0,0), 6)
            #escreve o texto
            newImage = cv2.putText(newImage, label, (top_x, top_y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL , 3, (0, 230, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    return newImage

#opções para carregar o modelo
options = {"model": "cfg/yolo-new.cfg",
          "load": -1,
          "gpu": 1.0}
#configura a rede com as opções
tfnet2 = TFNet(options)
#carrega a rede
tfnet2.load_from_ckpt()
#Captura video
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Cria janela chamada YOLO
cv2.namedWindow("Yolo")
while True:
   #Lê frame
   ret, frame = cam.read()
   #Reconhece objetos no frame  
   results = tfnet2.return_predict(frame)
   if results:
       print("\nResults---------------------------------------------------")
       for y in range(0, len(results)):
           #Para cada objeto reconhecido printa o nome e com qual confiança
           print("Label:%s\tConfidence:%f"%(results[y]['label'], results[y]['confidence']))
   #mostra imagem
   cv2.imshow('YoloV3',boxing(frame, results))

 #Se não encontra frame
   if not ret:
       break
   k = cv2.waitKey(1)
   #Se Clicar no Esc fecha
   if k%256 == 27:
       print("Escape hit, closing...")
       break
#Libera os recursos de software e hardware da câmera
cam.release()
#Destroi a janela
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

4 - My plate

[image: My video card]

5 - Cuda

[image: Cuda 9.0]

6 - cuDNN

[image: cuDNN]

7 - Pycharm

[image: tensorflow-gpu in pycharm]

The process goes on normally, but my GPU remains unused.

[image: Process]

[image: GPU Use]

Comment: "but the execution gives an error" - what's the error?

Comment: It makes no mistake. Just don't use the GPU.